# How to resolve reading and writing operations with /dev file as a kernel module in Linux?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Obviuosly, it's a unsuprising newbie's question after a lot of troubles with kernel programming. I try to launch a program that gets driver file in /dev folder available for some reading and writing (indeed, I realize it's rather unsafe idea, but I need strongly going ahead with all that experience). Let's look at a module source code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int init_module(void); // driver file initialization as opening it
void cleanup_module(void); // exec files removal ahead of shutting driver file
static int device_open(struct inode *, struct file *); // driver file opening
static int device_release(struct inode *, struct file *); // return of system resource control
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *); // reading from driver file
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *); // writing into driver file

#define SUCCESS 1
#define DEVICE_NAME "sample device"
#define BUF_LEN 80

static int Major; // device's major number
static int Device_Open = 0; // device access counter
static char message[BUF_LEN]; // buffer for both read and write operations
static char *message_ptr;

// list of basic operations executable by driver
static struct file_operations ops = {
        .read = device_read,
        .write = device_write,
        .open = device_open,
        .release = device_release
};

int init_module(void)
{
    Major = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &ops); // major number assignment

    // evaluate whether driver file is accessible
    if(Major < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Device registration attempt failed\n");
        return Major;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(Major, DEVICE_NAME); // cancelling driver registration in file system before exit
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Driver file of /dev/%s c %d 0 has been destroyed\n", DEVICE_NAME, Major);
    return;
}

static int device_open(struct inode * node, struct file * file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Trying access /dev/%s c %d 0\n", DEVICE_NAME, Major);
    static int counter = 0; // access counter initializing

    // file control evaluation
    if(Device_Open)
        return -EBUSY;

    Device_Open++; // increment counter to avert driver's immanent running
    sprintf(message, "This sentence displayed %d times\n", counter++);
    message_ptr = message;

    try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);

    return SUCCESS;
}

static int device_release(struct inode * node, struct file * file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Trying closure of /dev/%s c %d 0\n", DEVICE_NAME, Major);
    Device_Open--; // decrement counter to keep driver file removable as well
    module_put(THIS_MODULE);

    return SUCCESS;
}

static ssize_t device_read(struct file * file, char * ch, size_t num, loff_t * off)
{
    int read_bytes = 0; // output size
    printk(KERN_INFO "Trying read from /dev/%s c %d 0\n", DEVICE_NAME, Major);
    if(*message_ptr == 0)
        return 0;

    // loop-executed reading from file
    while(num && *message_ptr) {
        put_user(*(message_ptr++), ch++);
        num--;
        read_bytes++;
    }

    printk("%d bytes read, %d bytes to be handled", read_bytes, num);

    return read_bytes;
}


// updated stuff    
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off) 
{
    char message_from_user[BUF_LEN];    
    if(copy_from_user(message_from_user, buff, len)) return -EINVAL;
    printk(KERN_INFO "length of message:%d message:'%s'", (int)len,   message_from_user);
    return len; 
}
```

To test reading/writing, I use this code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>

extern int errno;

int main()
{
    int fd; // file descriptor id
    size_t cnt = 0; // input / output number of bytes
    size_t cnt_2 = 0;
    char inputBuffer[30] = "Device file is open"; // write operation buffer
    char outputBuffer[50]; // read operation buffer

    printf("Continuing with basics of Linux drivers...\n");

    // evaluate accessibility of driver file
    fd = open("/dev/dev", O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1) {
        close(fd);
        printf("File opening isn't completed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Driver file is open now\n");

    // writing from file
    cnt = write(fd, inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer));
    printf("Driver got written %d bytes\n", cnt);

    // read into file
    cnt = read(fd, outputBuffer, sizeof(outputBuffer));
    printf("Driver received %d bytes\n", cnt);

    int i = 0;

    // display an input message
    while(i < cnt) {
        printf("%c", outputBuffer[i]);
        printf("%s", "\n");
        i++;
    }

    close(fd); // wrap up driver connection and clear memory
    printf("Driver file is close\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Altough the module was built in as well as dev file was made by mknod (I run it on Ubuntu 18.04), I'm stuck at write operation due to some miscomprehension of driver calls in user/kernel spaces. Once I start my program, outputs are here as follows:

Continuing with basics of Linux drivers...
Driver file is open now
Driver got written -1 bytes

Followed by last line output, the system becomes inoperable (no response until I make off PC). That's a case I think of like a matter of memory control or, most probably, some driver file properties. However, user rights have been granted to reading / writing / executing, no access restrictions are inferable indeed. Hopefully, it's possible to point out to what's wrongness in the code posted here.

Comment: There is no logical code for write operation in the given driver code.device_write()  is an incomplete function.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code you don't handle the writing part.

```c
static ssize_t device_write(struct file * file, const char * ch, size_t num, loff_t * off)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Operation denied\n");
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

Thus there is no way your module can possibly work.

But your crash comes from memory accesses in your reading function (check this with `strace`).  I let you understand your issue. `dmesg` should help (or in the case your system panics you can make the log persistant to debug it after rebooting your system).

Comment: Thanks, I've added some stuff into device_write before trying again. Nonetheless, the main program runs into infinite workout every time when being executed. To specify, I start it, then three outputs appears successively - same I wrote in my question (-1 byte got written, surreal). However, since latest code revision, that is no longer too hard woes as all apps are operable, so I don't have to make PC off. Right now it looks like infinitely waiting process, but what a code section a bug exists in? Therefore I'm still seeking any insight to resolve my problem.

Comment: Well, edit your code to show what you tried or it will be hard to help you... If your does does an infinite loop maybe you don't return the length you read thus your code goes again and again with the same data... But hard to be sure without code.

Comment: I added some new stuff into device_write(), so far things are stuck as oddly as described above